# mathematics as a science of finding patterns

Tags: soft-question, education

Many months ago I read a (quite nice) article saying that mathematics is a systematic study on finding patterns. It went on to enumerate the different fields of mathematics (algebra, geometry, calculus, statistics) and what those corresponding patterns are.

Now I am looking for that article and I couldn't find it. Anyone who have read (or even have their own versions), please come and give a suggestion.

Comment: I select "mathematics is a systematic study on finding patterns" and first in google is https://nrich.maths.org/2148 - is this what you wanted?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Thanks for your help. I am looking for specifically Mathematics as a study of finding patterns. It then goes on to enumerate the different branches of mathematics (statistics = finding patterns in data, geometry = finding patterns in ... shapes? etc etc) I am searching for this and would like to revisit what it had to say about mathematics.

Comment: Was it, by any chance the introductory text that accompanies Keith Devlin's Introduction to Mathematical Thinking course on Coursera?

Comment: I was familiar decades ago with the idea that mathematics is largely about finding patterns. I think it was not a new idea even then. Enumeration of the kinds of patterns found in different fields of mathematics is a natural extension of that idea, so it would not surprise me if several writers have published works like the one you described. Further details (whatever you can remember) might help focus the search better.

Comment: One suggestion: you might try finding a helpful reference librarian, perhaps a mathematics specialist at a nearby university. "Can you find this article for me" is a kind of question that such people answer frequently.